# ResourceExhausted Error in colab - for Action Recognition using kinetics labels

Tags: tensorflow, action, github-pages, google-colaboratory

I tried to do Action Recognition using this Kinetics labels in **colab**. [I refer this link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/action_recognition_with_tf_hub.ipynb)

When I gave the input video below 2 MB this model was working fine. But if I give the input video more than 2 MB I got ResourceExhausted Error after few mins I got GPU memory usage is close to the limit.[image]
Even I terminate the notebook and start the new one I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the physical limitations of your hardware has been reached. It requires more GPU memory than there is available.

You could prevent this by reducing the models' batch size, or resize the resolution of your input video sequence.

Alternatively, you could try to use Google's cloud training to gain additional hardware resources, however it is not free.

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @YoungChul , Is it possible to run a live video in colab? If it's possible then How can I run a live video in colab with out any memory error? I'm using 4 Megapixel IP CCTV camera (live video)